# Samba 4 and SSH without password

Tags: ssh, single-sign-on, samba4

I've a question to Samba 4 and Kerberos. I've had a functional SSH with SSO. But now when I've installed Samba 4 it doesn't work and it seems, that nobody has found any solution yet. I just read, that it was really difficult and complicated or *On Windows all works fine, but on Linux I've no success yet* and so on.

The problem is, that Samba 4 implements Kerberos differently. And it seems to be somehow incompatible with Linux tools like SSH. When I run `sshd` in debug mode, I see, that it writes:

```
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No key table entry found matching host/bolbro.barbucha.local@
```

But I'm not able to add such principal to Samba principal database. (Although it does not exist, the `samba-tool spn add` writes, that it is affected by another user.)

My post may sound confusedly, but I've to say, that I don't exactly understand yet, what's the matter and may use in my text some terms wrong. Do you anybody have any expirience with Samba 4 and SSH client working without password? Have you ever succeeded at Samba 4 and SSO on Linux client?

Thanks a lot for any hint or explanation. (I'm using Debian Squeeze, Bolbro is the machine, the Samba 4 and SSHD runs on. The same problem affects the `ksu` as well.)

Comment: How did you create the keytab?

Comment: I executed samba-tool on server side `samba-tool domain exportkeytab /etc/krb5.keytab` and then I copied the `/etc/krb5.keytab` onto the client.

Comment: @schnikow: did you ever find a solution? I've hit the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably haven't found the solution of this problem yet, but something similar works on my computer now. To get NSLCD to work using GSSAPI, I made these commands on the server side:

```
#create an user with a random password
samba-tool user add --random-password ldap-connect
#the password must not expire
samba-tool user setexpiry --noexpiry ldap-connect
#create a SPN (security principal name)
samba-tool spn add nslcd/bolbro.barbucha.local ldap-connect
#export key table of the user ldap-connect
samba-tool domain exportkeytab krb5.nslcd.keytab --principal=ldap-connect
```

Each security principal (`nslcd`) is assigned to a machine (`bolbro.barbucha.local`) and the service using this SPN is authenticated as an user (`ldap-connect`). There can be always just one security principal *<service>/<machine>*. You cannot create `nslcd/bolbro.barbucha.local` again and assign it to some other user. The security principal `host/bolbro.barbucha.local` already exists. I thing today, that it may suffice to just export the key table of the user, the critical SPN is assigned to.

We'll see…

## Heuréka!

I found the solution today (2014-03-02). Yes, it is really so. I made these steps:

- joined the client to the domain: `net ads join -U administrator`, where `net` is one of Samba utilities
- uncomented within `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on server side and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on client side the line `GSSAPIAuthentication no` and overwrote `no` with `yes`; enabled similarly `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials` on the client side
- executed on both sides command `net ads keytab create` in order to export the needed keys into `/etc/krb5.keytab`
- added fully qualified server name into `/etc/hosts` on the server side

I don't know why, but when I executed `sshd` on the server side in debug-mode (`/usr/sbin/sshd -d`), I saw a message, that there is *no key table entry found matching host/bolbro@*. The expected server name (listed by `klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab` on the server side) is `bolbro.barbucha.local`. To append the server's IP-address and fully qualified name `bolbro.barbucha.local` to `/etc/hosts` solved the problem.

Comment: I upvoted you just for `Heuréka!`